# SalesForce Oauth BULK API using REST & JSON instead of CSV & SOAP

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0, salesforce, bulkinsert

I am trying to connect SalesForce via ConnectedAPP. I am successful to authorize and get the access and refresh tokens for the REST API operations.

I can able to post one lead into SF via API end points. I found that in the below [URL's](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/api-explorer/sobject/Lead)

I found bulk API [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_jobs_create.htm) also.

But in that, Soap API and csv are being used to to the operations of bulk inserts.But i am trying to do using bearer token and JSON as the payload to push data.

Please provide me some samples or a approach to achieve this via REST API bulk inserts.

Answer (score 1):

The Bulk API is not a SOAP API. Its endpoints accept payloads in XML and JSON format, and accepts batch data files in XML, JSON, and CSV formats.

You can use the access token supplied from your OAuth flow to authenticate to the Bulk API. You can choose to submit [job details](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/asynch_api_jobs_create.htm) in either JSON or XML. See [Prepare XML and JSON Files](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_asynch.meta/api_asynch/datafiles_xml_preparing.htm) for details of the data file format when using JSON input.

There are multiple example implementations of the Bulk API available in open source projects, such as [`salesforce-bulk`](https://github.com/heroku/salesforce-bulk).